# DataTables row count off by one (VB.Net / JQuery)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been searching with no luck for a resolution. I am returning a dataTable table that on the first page is returning one less row than requested. I have a default set to return 5 rows but it only returns 4. All pages after the first page return the correct count of rows. Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks,
Hugh

Comment: can you show ur effort

Comment: @Hugh Plummer please post your HTML and script .